# difference between two groups

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

So I have some data about a game and would like to find out if the expected values of the two groups that play this game are different.

I have 3 columns with 100 + rows of the data of the past game with: how many guys from group a who played, how many guys from group b who played and who won (a or b). The numbers of how many guys who played a single game vary from row to row.

I was thinking about calculating:

```
  list_a = (#a / (#a + #b)) * (1 if a won, 0 if b won) 
  list_b = (#b / (#a + #b)) * (0 if a won, 1 if b won)
```

And then doing a t.test(list_a,list_b,"equal") to see if there is a difference between both mu. I have to test if the chances of winning are fair, so a person of team a is equal to win against a person of team b.
Is this a correct way of checking this or what formula should i use ?

Comment: Maybe you should calculate something like this: https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda353.htm

Comment: yes I know how the t.test works, but I want to know if my formula is right, if I just use X = #a, y = #b I go and see if both have the same number of players playing and not wether the chances of winning of a player is equal.